# Mudar estilo - Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, front-end

Criei um arquivo e adicionei um menu de navegação usando Bootstrap, mas queria mudar algumas coisas como cor da fonte e outras coisas...
Criei um arquivo estilo.css e linkei na minha index, porém não muda em nada, tento colocar o nome da classe que usei no meu menu de navegação e mesmo assim não modifica nada.
Alguém poderia me ajudar.

Comment: O seu arquivo CSS esta linkado abaixo do CSS do bootstrap?

Comment: Edite a pergunta e adicione o seu código - que seja relacionado com o problema, não todo ele. Sem o código será impossível dizer o que está acontecendo.

Answer (score 3):

Bom, você consegue modificar algumas coisas "na mão" igual você citou ai, ou você **pode utilizar 2 formas**:

---

### Pelo site do Bootstrap

Pelo site do Bootstrap, há uma pagina que se chama "customize", lá você consegue alterar alguns estados de classes assim como cores, fontes e tudo mais.

http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Que ele ja te da o .css e o .js pronto para vc utilizar em seu projeto.

[image: bootstrap.zip gerado da pagina customize]

que por padrão ele utiliza o [LESS](http://lesscss.org/) para poder "compilar" o css

### Baixando o "fonte"

Se tu preferir consegue baixar o "fonte" do bootstrap e "compilar" ele utilizando o [SASS](http://sass-lang.com/) ou [LESS](http://lesscss.org/)

Por meio desta [Pagina de Download](http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#download)

### Extras

Tem sites que você consegue estilizar componentes em especifico do bootstrap como:

- [Navbar](https://work.smarchal.com/twbscolor/)
- [Buttons](http://blog.koalite.com/bbg/)

Ou se preferir um editor visual

- [Bootstrap Live Customizer](https://www.bootstrap-live-customizer.com/)

Comment: Interessante, não sabia que tinha todas essas ferramentas para customizar o bootstrap (apenas o customize dele próprio). Boa resposta!!! Nem sempre a melhor solução é tentar resolver "na mão", pois temos que lembrar que em alguns casos tem os seletores com `:hover` e `:focus`, e pode ser complicado fazer tudo na mão.

Comment: Siim, "fazer na mão" é só casos específicos. Do resto podemos estilizar tudo (Principalmente por essa ultima ferramenta ai, ela ja tem alguns temas muito legais prontos)